# Best way to parse json_decoded php array

Tags: php, parsing

what would be the best way to parse stringified one dimensional array?

input array

```
$inputArray = array(
  "id" => "foo",
  "name" => "bar",
  "money[0][amount]" => 30,
  "money[0][countryCode]" => "US",
  "money[1][amount]" => 25,
  "money[1][countryCode]" => "CA",
)
```

desired output array

```
$outputArray = array(
  "id" => "foo",
  "name" => "bar",
  "money" => array(
    [0] => array(
      "amount" => 30,
      "countryCode" => "US"
    ),
    [1] => array(
      "amount" => 25,
      "countryCode" => "CA"
    ),
  ),
)
```

Comment: You got that `$inputArray` from `json_decode()`? That's... unusual

Comment: can you show the actual json?

Comment: A small clarification just to be sure: for the array nested under `money` - presumably you want numeric indexes here, not literally `[0]`, `[1]` and so on?

Comment: It looks like you used stringify instead of serialize.

Comment: Sorry if my question made your day! For those who wonder how this is happened, my form is being sent through jQuery selector and initialized it as options['variables'] = new FormData($(options['variables'])[0]); in javascript.

and then, as Don' Panic says, options['variables'] is being stringified then sent to php server. and if you json_decode with second parameter as true, that monster is being born.

Comment: i can't just simply use $_REQUEST variable for some reason, so i was looking for some help. Thanks for your help guys!

Comment: if your happy with the posted answer that's great, but there better ways to do this that you are chosing to ignore.

Comment: @IdontDownVote yup you're absolutely right, Would you mind to give me an advice of better way to pass formdata using jQuery selector and Formdata object?

Comment: can you post that as a new question with the relevant code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert your array in a query url and parse it ... like this

```
<?php

$inputArray = array(
  "id" => "foo",
  "name" => "bar",
  "money[0][amount]" => 30,
  "money[0][countryCode]" => "US",
  "money[1][amount]" => 25,
  "money[1][countryCode]" => "CA",
);

$url = http_build_query($inputArray);
parse_str($url, $outputArray);

print_r($outputArray);
```

Live example: https://3v4l.org/DAAUM

Comment: ambulance at bottom of cliff approach, how about fixing the input.

Comment: Well, fix the input may be better, but that would be another question ...

Comment: @IdontDownVote If fixing the input isn't an option (e.g. he's relying on external JSON that literally has a key `"money[0][amount]": 30`), this is probably the cleanest workaround OP can get.